# Using Contains to search in SQLite in non-English text returns more results than expected

Tags: c#, wpf, sqlite, entity-framework-6

I'm using Sqlite+EF in WPF application, when I search for text in the db contains non-English letters I got the rows I expected + another rows don't know why it came.
What I do is:
`dbContext.MyTable.Where(w => w.Name.Contains(someNonEnglishTextHere))`

- DB is Sqlite3
- Encoding is UTF-8
- Column `Name` in `MyTable` has `Collate` as `NOCASE`
- I'm using EF6

When invistigated the sql query formed by EF, `Contains` repalced by `CHARINDEX` instead of `LIKE`, is there any way I can force EF to use `LIKE` ? maybe this is the solution if I can do it.

Comment: Have you solved that? i have same problem with cyrilic...

Comment: Never solved it, Searched in memory so I can get rid of searching in DB.

Answer (score 1):

You can replact the CHARINDEX function by injecting db interceptor.
Add you interceptor to the dbcontext.

```
class MyDBContext: DbContext
{
    static MyDBContext()
    {
        DbInterception.Add(new SqliteInterceptor());
    }
}
```

Finish your interceptor like this:

```
class SqliteInterceptor : IDbCommandInterceptor
{
    private static Regex replaceRegex = new Regex(@"\(CHARINDEX\((.*?),\s?(.*?)\)\)\s*?>\s*?0");

    public void NonQueryExecuted(DbCommand command, DbCommandInterceptionContext<int> interceptionContext)
    {
    }

    public void NonQueryExecuting(DbCommand command, DbCommandInterceptionContext<int> interceptionContext)
    {
    }

    public void ReaderExecuted(DbCommand command, DbCommandInterceptionContext<DbDataReader> interceptionContext)
    {
    }

    public void ReaderExecuting(DbCommand command, DbCommandInterceptionContext<DbDataReader> interceptionContext)
    {
        ReplaceCharIndexFunc(command);
    }

    public void ScalarExecuted(DbCommand command, DbCommandInterceptionContext<object> interceptionContext)
    {
    }

    public void ScalarExecuting(DbCommand command, DbCommandInterceptionContext<object> interceptionContext)
    {
        ReplaceCharIndexFunc(command);
    }

    private void ReplaceCharIndexFunc(DbCommand command)
    {
        bool isMatch = false;
        var text = replaceRegex.Replace(command.CommandText, (match) =>
        {
            if (match.Success)
            {
                string paramsKey = match.Groups[1].Value;
                string paramsColumnName = match.Groups[2].Value;
                //replaceParams
                foreach (DbParameter param in command.Parameters)
                {
                    if (param.ParameterName == paramsKey.Substring(1))
                    {
                        param.Value = string.Format("%{0}%", param.Value);
                        break;
                    }
                }
                isMatch = true;
                return string.Format("{0} LIKE {1}", paramsColumnName, paramsKey);
            }
            else
                return match.Value;
        });
        if (isMatch)
            command.CommandText = text;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've solved my problem by rewriting functions

```
 [SQLiteFunction(Arguments = 1, FuncType = FunctionType.Scalar, Name = "Lower")]
    class CustomLower : SQLiteFunction
    {
        public override object Invoke(object[] args)//characters for the growth of
        {
            return args[0].ToString().ToLower();
        }
    }

    [SQLiteFunction(Arguments = 2, FuncType = FunctionType.Scalar, Name = "CHARINDEX")]
    class CustomCharIndex : SQLiteFunction
    {
        public override object Invoke(object[] args)//characters for the growth of
        {
            return args[1].ToString().IndexOf(args[0].ToString(), StringComparison.Ordinal) + 1;
        }
    }
```